# Threading on UI Panel?

Tags: python, scripting, interface

I'm trying to create a simple menu in blender that will execute a long calculation. So I'm trying to execute that operation in parallel. But in my code when I click in "Exec" button blender get stuck until finish operation.
Is there a way to run "Exec"  and continuing using blender interface?

Simple code just to example:

````
import bpy
from bpy.types import Panel, Operator
import threading
 
class ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel(Panel):
    bl_label = "Conf"
    bl_idname = "ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Menu"
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator("addonname.myop_operator")
 
class ADDONNAME_OT_my_op(Operator):
    bl_label = "Exec"
    bl_idname = "addonname.myop_operator" 
    def execute(self, context):        
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Exec")
        ################################################## threading ################################
        threading.Thread(target=Exec()).start()
        
        
        return {'FINISHED'}
 
classes = [ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel, ADDONNAME_OT_my_op]
 
def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)      
 
def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
 
 ######################## Exec #########################
 
def Exec():
    print("really long time operation")
 
 #######################################################
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
import bpy, time
from bpy.types import Panel, Operator
import threading

class ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel(Panel):
    bl_label = "Conf"
    bl_idname = "ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Menu"
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator("addonname.myop_operator")

class ADDONNAME_OT_my_op(Operator):
    bl_label = "Exec"
    bl_idname = "addonname.myop_operator" 
    def execute(self, context):        
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Exec")
        ################################################## threading ################################
        threading.Thread(target=Exec).start()

        return {'FINISHED'}

classes = [ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel, ADDONNAME_OT_my_op]

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)      

def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)

######################## Exec #########################

def Exec():
    print("run")
    t = time.time()
    target_time = t + 10
    fn = time.time

    while fn() < target_time:
        pass

    print(f"It take {fn() - t} sec")
    print("done")
#######################################################

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```